# Copy Row in excel using button but button should not follow

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with lots of sections. I created one macro and then on each section I have one button. I have connected <strike>button to that macro</strike> macro to that button.

```
 On button click :
```

- existing row is going to copy
- add a new row
- past the content of the first row

Everything is working fine. **Problem is this that the button is also copied each time when I copy row.** I do not  want that button to be copied and it should remain in previous row. OR The button should be place on the last row.

Here is code.

```
Sub Button_AddRow()
Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
b.TopLeftCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
b.TopLeftCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

b.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
b.TopLeftCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
b.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
b.TopLeftCell.Offset(2).EntireRow.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Cells(b.TopLeftCell.Offset(1).Row, 1).Value = ""

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

[image: See how many button, coming there, I need just one button at the end]

Tried a lot but not getting success.

Comment: So the mainly you want to copy current row and paste it as an adjacent new row? No need to copy the button right?

Answer (score 0):

Why refer to the button in your code ? You could use ActiveCell:

```
Sub Button_AddRow()
   Dim r As Range
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect
   Set r = ActiveCell.EntireRow
   ....
```

I guess your problem will disappear. Of course, the user would have to click somewhere on the "right" line first.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on iDevelop's answer, you could use the Button's TopLeftCell to get the address of the row you want, and then clean up your code like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button_AddRow()

Dim b As Object, cs As Integer, cel As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
cel = b.TopLeftCell.Address

Range(cel).Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(2).Insert

Range(cel).Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(2).Value = Range(cel).Value

Cells(Range(cel).Offset(1).Row, 1).Value = ""

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah, I trid Scott code and its working. It creating new rows. My requirement is to create new row and then move that button from previous row to the last row. Client need Addrow button at the end of line on each section. Beside this new cretead rows have not same merged column that i have on the last line...so again I am stuck....